# 2d array size based on input

Tags: java, arrays

I have a code where in, an array is to be defined, in which the size is based on user input. How do I do that?

My code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of layers in the network:");
    int Nb_Layers = in.nextInt();
    int[] Hidden_layer_len = new int[Nb_Layers];


    for (int i = 0; i < Nb_Layers-1; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the length of layer" +(i+1)+":");
        Hidden_layer_len[i] = in.nextInt();

        if(i == 0)
        {
            double [][] E = new double[Hidden_layer_len[i]][1];//This is the array I need based on the size mentioned.

        }
    }

    System.out.println(E);
}
```

I want this to be a 2D array. Any suggestions would be appreciated. thank you!

Comment: You want the 2D array to have `Nb_Layers` rows and `Hidden_layer_len[i]` columns ?

Comment: Nope, for now it is Hidden_layer_len[i] rows and one column. but the number of columns will change as per my requirements.

Comment: You could use a ArrayList - it would work for you! Otherwise you could allocate a specific size for your array. If it doesn't fit any more - you can copy it to an bigger reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the array outside the for loop and assign inside. E.g.

```
double[][] E = null;
for (int i = 0; i < Nb_Layers - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the length of layer" + (i + 1) + ":");
    Hidden_layer_len[i] = in.nextInt();

    if (i == 0) {
        E = new double[Hidden_layer_len[i]][1];
    }
}
```

This way it will be available when you print it at the end.
By the way you probably want to print it like this

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(E));
```

Comment: But is it advisable to initialize E as null? i read in a few documents to avoid null as much as possible..

Comment: What you read is correct. But in this case the compiler/IDE will complain that `E` might not have been initialized when it is used to print. `Arrays.deepToString(E)` will print "null" if `E` is null so little harm in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification.. Big help :)